# Dynamic pivot - Incorrect syntax error near @cols

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I have a view in Sql Server called '`ITEMS_PRICE`'. 
Some of it's columns are the '`Name`' column and '`FormulaResult_Cost`' column.

What I am trying to do, is using dynamic pivot, make all rows of '`Name`' field as columns and take as value, the value of '`FormulaResult_Cost`'.

---

Here is my SQL Query:

```
    DECLARE   @query   NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE   @cols   NVARCHAR(4000)

      SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + QUOTENAME(p.Name) 
                    from ITEMS_PRICE AS p
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,0,'')  

    --select STUFF(@cols, 1,0,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT p.ItemCode, p.ItemName, p.ItmsGrpCod, p.ItmsGrpNam, p.Name, p.FormulaResult_Cost, ' + @cols + '
                 from 
                    ITEMS_PRICE as p
                pivot 
                (
                    max(p.FormulaResult_Cost)
                    for p.Name in (' + '[' @cols + ']' + ')
                ) AS t'

    EXECUTE(@query)
```

---

The error that I get is:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29 Incorrect syntax near  '@cols'.*

---

Also, I don't want the dynamic pivot to have any aggregate functions. I just read in some forums that you have to use, at least `max()` function in order to be correct the `for ... in` code.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `+` before `@cols` on this line: `for p.Name in (' + '[' @cols + ']' + ')` should be `for p.Name in (' + '[' + @cols + ']' + ')`.

But I don't believe you need the extra square brackets in there, as the `QUOTENAME` method will add them, so it should read:

```
for p.Name in (' + @cols + ')
```

Also, if you're doing `for p.Name in (@cols)`, your `STUFF` function should return comma separated values, so I would update your declaration to to include a comma after the `distinct`:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(p.Name) 
            from ITEMS_PRICE AS p
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,0,'')
```

**Full query:**

```
DECLARE   @query   NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE   @cols   NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(p.Name) 
            from ITEMS_PRICE AS p
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,0,'') 

--select STUFF(@cols, 1,0,'')

set @query = 'SELECT p.ItemCode, p.ItemName, p.ItmsGrpCod, p.ItmsGrpNam, 
                     p.Name, p.FormulaResult_Cost, ' + @cols + '
             from 
                ITEMS_PRICE as p
            pivot 
            (
                max(p.FormulaResult_Cost)
                for p.Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) AS t'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the error:

" Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'KOUZINES'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'TSEKOULATOURA ISIA])
            ) AS t'.
"


in ' ' there are some of the rows  values of the 'Name' column. Some of the rows of this column, are 2 words with a space between them. I don't know if this has some relation with it.

Comment: Now the error is " Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','. "

Comment: What does this bit do at the end of your `STUFF`? --> `,1,0,'')`? You may need to add the comma into the empty quotes there too, so ite reads: `,1,0,',')`

Comment: one easy way to get the last details fixed is to PRINT instead of execute and copy/paste your results in the query editing window. This way you have all your syntax checking tools available and can easily spot the problem. Also, the lat part of the stuff command should look like this: ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

Comment: @Tanner the error remains the same if I put a comma in the stuff too or no. The line that the problem appears is line 2 which is only a declaration so I believe that there is something else the problem. But thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: @Tristan I tried to change the last and the error is similar to my previous: "_Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ']'._"

Comment: Also @Tristan , if I change it to  `1,**1**,''` like you said, when I do `print` like you also said, I have this result:
`SELECT p.ItemCode, p.ItemName, ... , p.FormulaResult_Cost, **DIAFORES KATASKEVES][ELEVATOR]....`
But when I use `1,**0**,''` I have this result :  
`SELECT p.ItemCode, p.ItemName, ... , p.FormulaResult_Cost, **[**DIAFORES KATASKEVES][ELEVATOR]....` 
So I think that is correct to write zero in this function. But I am not sure what this function does so I may be wrong.

Comment: It seems your column names contain brackets ][ in between. This would seriously mess up the dynamic query. can you try QUOTENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(p.Name,']',')'),'[','(')) ?

Comment: There is still a problem -> _Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ELEVATOR'._ . I did it in the manual way. I know It's not practical or good way but I did my job. Thank you very much for your time..

Answer (score -1):

Add `+` before `@cols`. (`'['  @cols + ']'`)

```
set @query = 'SELECT p.ItemCode, p.ItemName, p.ItmsGrpCod, 
                     p.ItmsGrpNam, p.Name, p.FormulaResult_Cost, ' + @cols + '
              FROM 
                    ITEMS_PRICE as p
                pivot 
                (
                    max(p.FormulaResult_Cost)
                    for p.Name in (''' + @cols + ''')
                ) AS t'
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the error:

" Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'KOUZINES'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'TSEKOULATOURA ISIA])
            ) AS t'.
"


in ' ' there are some of the rows  values of the 'Name' column. Some of the rows of this column, are 2 words with a space between them. I don't know if this has some relation with it.